# Set a range to an entire column with index number

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm building a function that takes a column number as an input to return the highest value in the column.

I need to work with an entire column with a column index number. The following code works but I need an index number instead of using "B:B" to reference the column.

```
Set rng = Range("B:B")
```

When I use the following code, everything seems to break down. It always returns a 0 even though the highest number is 44. Can you see what I am doing wrong? It worked perfectly when I used "B:B" as a range.

```
Set rng = Range(Columns(2),Columns(2))
```

It doesn't seem to recognize anything in the range. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Those lines of code work for me.  What do you mean when you say "everything seems to break down"?  Can you provide more code showing what's not working and if you're getting any errors?

Comment: use `columns(2)` only. `Set rng =  columns(2)`

Comment: Instead of returning the highest number in the column, it returns a 0.

Comment: Why do you expect `Set rng = Range()` to return `44`? It's just setting a range. You can also just do `Set rng = Columns(2).EntireColumn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng As Range

    '~~> This will let you work with Col B
    Set Rng = Columns(2)
    '~~> This will give you the Max in that column
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is golden! Simpler than what I was trying to do

Answer (score -1):

This is from a solution I found a while back:

```
    Dim x, y As Int
    Dim rng As Range
    x = 1 ' For A
    y = 4 ' For D
    Set rng = Columns(Chr(64 + x) & ":" & Chr(64 + y))
```

Source: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/114025-visual-basic-applications-select-multiple-columns-using-column-number.html